# Convert "binary string" to "const char*" for send (web server)

Tags: c++, http, binary

I want send `binary data` with function `send()`

**functions:**

```
void ssend(const char* data){
    send(socket_fd, data, strlen(data), 0);
}

bool readFile(const char* path){
    std::ifstream ifile(path);
    if(ifile){
        if(!ifile.is_open()){
            ErrorPage("403");
            return true;
        }
        std::string sLine;

        std::string Header = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nConnection: Keep-Alive\nKeep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100\nServer: BrcontainerSimpleServer/0.0.1 (Win32) (Whitout Compiler code)\n\n";
        ssend(Header.c_str());

        while(!ifile.eof()){
            getline(ifile, sLine);
            cout << "String: " << sLine << endl;
            cout << "const char*: " << sLine.c_str() << endl;

            ssend(sLine.c_str());
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Test:**

```
...
while (1) {
    socket_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&client_addr_length);
    readFile( httpPath );
    recv(socket_fd, request, 32768, 0);
    closesocket(socket_fd);
}
...
```

When converting to `binary string` with `.c_str()`, data disappear. How to solve this problem?

how to send `binary data` with the function `send()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

```
void ssend(const std::string& data)
{
  send(socket_fd, data.data(), data.length(), 0);
}
```

or:

```
ssend(const std::vector<char>& data)
{
  send(socket_fd, &data[0], data.size(), 0);
}
```

If you are reading binary data from the file you will need to deal with that as well (e.g. open the file with `ios::binary`, use `read()` rather than `getline()`).  You probably want to use some sort of encoding to send binary data out from a web server though.

Answer (score 3):

In C and C++, strings are terminated with a character with the value of zero (`'\0'`). So when you say "binary string", you are mixing things that don't go together since binary data is not the same as a string.

Instead of a string, use a `BYTE` array and pass the length as an additional argument so you know how many bytes to send.

Your use of `strlen()` will stop counting as soon as it encounters the string terminator.

Comment: std::string can hold binary data so if the OP doesn't convert to a C string he can make that work... (or vector<char>)

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean to suggest that it couldn't be made to work but I don't consider it ideal. Aside from the null-terminator issue, there is also the issue of Unicode. So, I don't know what his `send()` method does, but I kind of think it should send bytes.

Comment: I think his send() is sockets API.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan, I used `<vector>`, +1 for you